# How to debug Chrome child process crashes (Aw-Snap pages) in gdb?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, gdb, stack-trace

I'm using the following command on Linux to debug Chrome:

```
$ gdb -ex 'set follow-fork-mode child' -ex run --args /usr/lib/chromium/chromium -g
```

which gives the following output:

```
Starting program: /usr/lib/chromium/chromium -g
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0xf0b7ab40 (LWP 2602)]
[New process 2604]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Inferior 2 (process 2604) exited normally]
(gdb) Created new window in existing browser session.
(gdb)
```

The web-browser is started, but it seems that `gdb` doesn't follow it anymore. Any tab crashes (`Aw, Snap!` pages) are not taken into account and quitting the browser doesn't change any output.

I've tried to add `-ex 'set detach-on-fork off'`, but then it doesn't start at all.

Given above, which parameters should I add to display stack traces of *Aw-Snap* pages?

Comment: I guess this is caused by Chrome render process switching PID namespaces. Unfortunately, I don't know how to workaround that. Maybe disable sandboxing in Chrome using command line flags?

Comment: See also: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/71.0.3562.1/docs/linux_debugging.md